# Sharing button in Salesforce Platform licence custom objects

Tags: custom-object, administration, profile, sharing-rule, owd

I am created one custom object name is Test. after i have imported 50 records data to Test object. here i have two users system administrator and salesforce platform user. my requirement is need to visible "**Sharing**" button on "salesforce platform license" user login Test object. 
My sharing rules is

```
  1. Test object "Default Internal Access" is Private
  2. Test object Sharing Rules

   Action    Criteria           Shared With     Access Level
 Test: Status equals True       Role: AAAA       Read/Write
```

without enable Custom Object Permissions "view all" and "modify all" options on profile how can i show "**sharing**" button above Test object in "salesforce platform license" user login.

Comment: Have you added the button to the page layout?

Comment: @David Reed: Thank you for your quick response.  yes, i have added sharing button on page layout. standard user can able to see and edit the records created by admin but sharing button in not visible on detail page when user want to share that record to others.  Can you please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: If anyone's looking for this in the Lightning UI, look no more.  There **is still *NO* Sharing button in the Lightning UI**.  See this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339349&type=1&mode=1) and this [IdeaExchange idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LmluQAC).

Confirmed as of the Winter '20 release.  Crazy that this still hasn't been prioritized...

Answer (score 1):

Users will only see the Sharing button when a number of criteria are met, including:

- The Sharing button is on the page layout.
- The organization-wide default is not Public Read/Write.
- The user has permission to share the record.

The final point appears to be what's tripping you up here. Your platform users don't own the records (the system administrator does) and they're not above the owner in the role hierarchy. As a consequence, they don't have the right to share that particular record. Offering them read/write access doesn't grant permission to share to other users.